# How to find update command in all linux distro?

Tags: upgrade

I need same method for find update command in all linux distro e.g gentoo ubuntu arch and other guys

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you asking for a way to know what's the command used by any OS to update packages/applications?

Comment: There is no generic "update" command.  You need to know (or choose) which package manager is used by each distro.  `apt`, `snappy`, `yum`, `pacman` all have different arguments so `pacman -Syu` may work for some distros while you need `apt update && apt upgrade` for others. `uname -v` might contain the distro name if your question is more about how to know which distro you are using.

Comment: you can use `pkcon` from packagekit.  the most distro have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a single update command for all Linux distributions. It depends on your package manager.

- Debian, Ubuntu: `apt-get`
- SUSE: `zypper`
- RedHat: `yum`
- Fedora, CentOS: `dnf`
- Mandriva, Mageia: `urpmi`
- Slackware: pkgtools and `slackpkg`
- Salix, Vector: `slapt-get`
- Zenwalk: `netpkg`
- Sabayon: `equo`
- Arch: `pacman`
- Puppy: `ppm`
- Alpine: `apk`

And these are just some of the ones that I  have tried.

Syntax to update the package list is also different: `zypper refresh`, `dnf check-update`, `urpmi.update -a`, `slackpkg update`, `slapt-get --update`,  `pacman -Sy` and so on.

It should be possible to write a shell script that checks on what distro it runs and execute the correct package manager. Be aware though, that dependency-trees and package names may also be different, which may complicate things even more.